# How would you say "my friends and I"?

Tags: grammar, translation

I feel that

> i miei amici e io

is a bad translation.

What would be the grammatically correct way to say it?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @CarloRevelli!

Comment: "i miei amici e io" I think is the right translation. Why do you think it is bad?

Comment: "I miei amici e io" is totally fine; mind that using the euphonic "d" before words starting with a vowel is usually preferred in order to articulate the two toghether with more ease (i.e. using "I miei amici ed io" as opposed to "I miei amici e io") : http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/d-eufonica_(La_grammatica_italiana)/.

Comment: @egreg I don't see the ambiguity (perhaps you can point that out?), but the second point I'm sorry doesn't make sense at all, "I" is obviously a vowel.

Comment: If you are satisfied with one of the answers to your question, please consider the option to "accept" an answer by clicking a checkmark next to that answer.

Answer (score 5):

"My friends and I" would be generally  translated as "Io e i miei amici", " I miei amici ed io" is also correct.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=io%20e%20i%20miei%20amici%2C%20I%20miei%20amici%20ed%20io%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cio%20e%20i%20miei%20amici%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20miei%20amici%20ed%20io%3B%2Cc0) *Io e i miei amici*  vs *I miei amici ed io*

Answer (score 3):

"*I miei amici ed io*" is the better translation that you can do. Please, note two things:

- "*ed*", instead of "*e*" has the final "*d*", which is better suited since the following letter is a vowel;
- In Italian, it is better to put the first person at the last "place": putting it at the beginning ("*io e i miei amici*") sounds too "egocentric", and it should be avoided (see [here](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/en/node/7913) also).

Comment: Very interesting link: as usual several grammars essentially say that “Io e te” is the form everybody uses, but that's incorrect. Which is silly.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, you are right. That's the reason why I'd wish to add this answer of mine. In fact, "io e te" is correct indeed, but it doesn't take into consideration the "bon ton" aspect of the communication...an aspect that, maybe, is sometimes ignored by "strict-grammar" books.

Comment: Grammars may take the “bon ton” into consideration, but if Italian speakers don't, grammars should adapt, not conversely.

Comment: Sadly enough, that's it...

Comment: To me it sounds more natural to say it the other way round, Ngram, for what it is worth, seems to confirm that.

Comment: @Josh61: Thank you for commenting at this. I totally respect your tought, but I give more credit to Accademia della Crusca than Ngram (we can say a lot of things, here...recalling egreg's comment: many Italians speak in a certain way, but the correct way could be another).

Comment: With all respect to our Accademia, usage is also to be taken into account IMO, I showed Ngran results because they actually seem to confirm my impression, what I'd naturally say or I'd expect to hear. Probably the "Bob-ton" has got lost along its way....

Comment: As a native speaker, "i miei amici ed io" sounds wrong, although it is possibly correct. In Italy you would most definitely hear more often, if not always: "io e i miei amici".